# Will installing a file manager app void the device/Android warranty?

Tags: applications, installation, file-management, warranty

One of the frustrating things about HTC is that I cannot manage my files which have been downloaded. On the marketplace, there are some apps which allow you to do this such as:

- Astro File manager
- eFile
- Root Explorer

If I install a file explorer app, will that void my warranty with HTC or Android?

Answer (score 13):

No, you won't invalidate your warranty.*  Keep in mind that Root Explorer requires root, though, and rooting will invalidate your warranty.  I personally love Root Explorer, so I recommend the non-root version: [Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.explorer).

<sub>* I haven't read your warranty, but I've never heard of a condition that bizarre. This is not legal advice; I am not a lawyer.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No, using a file manager will not invalidate your warranty. Rooting often will though. On my phone, I personally use Astro File Manager.

If you want a solution to manage all your files from the desktop, our company produces a solution called [SnapPea](http://www.snappea.com). It's an easy way to manage contacts, apps, music, and videos from your Windows desktop.